# For imbalanced binary classification what should be the value of "scoring" In cross_val_score()

Tags: cross-validation

For imbalanced binary classification what should be the value of "scoring" in cross_val_score()

Is scoring is same as accuracy in cross_val_score() .

For binary classification can we used f1_weighted or f1_macro.

By dataset is imbalanced binary class classification. When I used train_test_split it gives 62% accuracy and when I used cdoss_val_score ot gives 90% accuracy.
What mistakes I'm making?